# Eliminating comments from a code of sourcecode file and printing the code(without the comments in the file)

Tags: java

**For example, consider the following text:**

```
import java.util.*;

/* My program
by           */
public class Program {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello, world!"); // a println
   }

   public static /* Hello there */ void foo() {
      System.out.println("Goodbye!"); // comment here
   } /* */
}
```

If the file contained this text, the program should output the following text:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello, world!");
   }

   public static  void foo() {
      System.out.println("Goodbye!");
   }
}
```

**Well i wrote the code for it and named a function called `stripComments` which accepts a scanner input of the file in question :**

```
public void stripComments(Scanner input){

    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        boolean flag=false;

        String scan=input.nextLine();
        Scanner line=new Scanner(scan);
        while(line.hasNext()){

            String token=line.next();
            if(token.equals("/*")){
                while(line.hasNext()){

                    if(line.next().equals("\\*")){
                        token=line.next();
                        flag=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!flag){
                    while(input.hasNextLine()){
                        scan=input.nextLine();
                        line=new Scanner(scan);


                        while(line.hasNext()){

                            token=line.next();
                            if(token.equals("*\\")){

                                token=line.next();
                                flag=true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(token+" ");

            }


        }
        System.out.println();


    }

}
```

However the output that is produced is :

```
import java.util.*;
```

That's it!!!!

Can anybody point out where i went wrong?

Comment: well i know i didn't address the (\\\) constraint , but that i can take care of :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you set `flag` to true, you consume the whole input in the second

```
while(input.hasNextLine()){ 
  //...
}
```

block.

Also, (once you fixed that): once you set the `flag`, you never unset it

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your code are you looking for `*/`, which marks the end of a multi-line comment. As result, once the comment begins on line 2, it never ends.

Also, for this particular task I'd recommend looking at the input one character at a time, rather than one `Scanner` token at a time. Coupled with a simple [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), this could lead to a simple and robust implementation.

Answer (score 0):

you should use 2 regulars expressions (for /**/ and //)  on the whole file content instead of working line by line.